# SQL Query to change rownum as text changes in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g

I'm stuck with a query wherein i need to change rownum or any running serial no. back to its original value as soon as it founds change of text of second column.
I'm using Oracle 11g.

For Eg. My Data is

```
    ________ 
   | EMP_CD |
   |--------| 
   |  D123  |
   |--------| 
   |  D123  | 
   |--------| 
   |  D123  |
   |--------| 
   |  F743  |
   |--------|  
   |  F743  |
   |________|
```

So Now What I'm expecting is

```
 _______ ________ 
| SR NO | EMP_CD |
|-------|--------| 
|   1   |  D123  |
|-------|--------| 
|   2   |  D123  | 
|-------|--------| 
|   3   |  D123  |
|-------|--------| 
|   1   |  F743  |
|-------|--------|  
|   2   |  F743  |
|_______|________|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select row_number() over (partition by emp_cd order by null) as sr_no, emp_cd
from   your_table
order by emp_cd, sr_no;
```

ORDER BY is optional.

Comment: Thank a lot @mathguy

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`row_number()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) analytic function:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_cd ORDER BY 1) AS sr_no, emp_cd
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: Thanks @Mureinik! Got Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `row_number()` analytic function